# How to solve this Pub / Sub acknowledge Issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, publish-subscribe

I wrote a serverside / fullstack library called React Server that mimicks React's reactive coding patterns. It allows you to use TSX on the serverside, promoting all kinds of benefits the React world has to offer.

It uses *hooks*, *states*, and *components* and implements a similar rendering and lifecycle approach. It uses GraphQL to consume backend services aka *components* which provide a 2 way binding of components between the server and client using a `useComponent` hook on the frontend.

In order to synchronize states it uses GraphQL subscriptions / PubSub. When a `setState` call or a `useClientEffect` mutates a *serverside* state the component *rerenders* and publishes the updated state to the client where it is reflected in the `useComponent` hook.

This works surprisingly well and I played around with it a lot. I have one little timing problem where the client receives "stale" data due to how the lifecycle events work.

Suppose I have a ViewCounter component on the serverside which keeps track of page views.

Now when a client / user loads the page a serverside effect is being called which increases the counter by one. Suppose the following TSX component.

```
const ViewCounter = () => {
    const [views, setViews] = useState(0);
    // A client effect is being executed when a component is rendered in the *context* of a client.
    useClientEffect(() => {
        setViews(views + 1);
    });
    return <ServerSideProps views={views} />

};
```

Now suppose the client loads the page and the effect is being executed. What's rendered to the client and returned in the request is the **old** state before `setViews` was being called.

Now normally a *rerender* of the component would cause the updated state to be published to the client. However, this happens so fast that the client didn't yet subscribe to any state changes.

How can I ensure that the updated stated is sent to the client when a `useClientEffect` mutates a state on the server?

I have a few ideas:

- Pass a flag from the client in the subscription call to indicate that a state should be published again after subscribing.
- Acknowledge each sent message
- Add a new effect `useAwaitSubscription` which waits until the client subscribed to state updates until it rerenders.

I'm not sure what option is better and if there are viable alternatives. You can observe the "faulty" behavior live at the projects website: https://state-less.cloud.

If you open the page in one tab, the view counter at the bottom shows an outdated result. If you duplicate the page to a second tab you can see that the counter jumps by **2** instead of increasing by one. This is because the client is now subscribed to changes and the `useClientEffect` causes a rerender on the server side, publishing the now correct state to all **subscribed** clients. The second tab however receives a stale response one render cycle behind.

- The same problem also happens after a server restart when the "cache" is cold and states need to be fetched from the database.

Due to the reactive nature all render calls are synchronous and the server doesn't wait for a database response and instead sends a cached value. It then publishes the value stored in the database once received to all subscribed clients. If the client hasn't subscribed yet and doesn't receive the published response, then it misses the latest render result and the server doesn't send it again because it assumes that it already sent out the latest value.

I think I need to fire a 'subscribed' event with the subscription key as argument and wait until a subscription before publishing a state.

A problem I see with this is when a client renders a component and disconnects after triggering a render on the serverside but before it sends a subscription event, so I would need to add a timeout which would leave me with the situation that very slow connections might receive a cached response but not the updated state from an effect or a database response.